# What is $x-y$ given $x/y$

Tags: ratio

If I know $x$ divided by $y,$ how can I work out $x-y$ from that? Suppose $x>y.$
Is this even possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Say $\frac{x}{y}=z$. This implies $x=yz$ , hence we get $x-y=yz-y=y(z-1)$ But without any further information we cannot determine $x-y$. If we , for example , know $y$ , we can do it.

Comment: In the special case $\frac{x}{y}=1$ , we can actually determine $x-y$. It is $0$ in this case because we have $x=y$.

Comment: If you knew both $x-y$ and $x/y$, then by a standard argument you would know both $x$ and $y$ as separate values.  So one way to think about this is you need two equations to determine two unknowns.

Answer (score 6):

Note that $\frac{4}{2} = \frac{2}{1}$, but $4-2=2 \neq 1 = 2-1$.

So the answer to your question is negative